# How is the area of a square of side length $L \in \mathbb{R}^+$ derived?

Tags: calculus, integration, area

I know that the area of a square of unit side length is, by an axiom, one square unit. So bascially, if $L=1 \Longrightarrow  A = 1 \times 1 = 1$

I also know, that the area of a square of side length $L \in \mathbb{N}^+$ is derived thus:

> We have a square of side length $L \in \mathbb{N}^+$. We can divide this square to smaller squares of unit side length, such that the smaller squares cover the entire larger square and do not overlap. By an axiom, the sum of the areas of the smaller squares equals the area of the larger square. By another axiom, the area of a square of side length $1$ is $1$ square unit.
>   We obviously have $L \times L$ squares of side length $1$, so we have, in total $L^2$ small squares. We can come to the conclusion that $A=L^2 \times 1 = L^2$.

**How do I do the same for a square having side length $L \in \mathbb{R}^+$?**

Obviously, the first method is not applicable; For example, having $L=\sqrt{2}$, I can't divide the square into unit squares, since $\sqrt{2}$ is not an integer.

Comment: What is your full list of axioms?

Comment: You could extend the argument for $L \in \mathbb{Q}$ by scaling your square appropiately. Then I suppose you could take a rational sequence of side lengths approaching $L$. But then you are relying on $f(x) = x^2$ being a continuous function. 

So I guess in the end, @MatthewLeingang 's question as to what you are allowed to assume is important.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang 
(1) The area of a square with a side of length one unit is defined to be one square unit

(2) If we divide a polygon to a finite number of smaller, not overlapping polygons, the sum of the smaller polygons' area is equal to the area of the original polygon

(3) Congruent polygons have equal areas

Comment: If that is the complete list, you will only be able to define area for rectangles with rational side lengths.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang What other axioms would I need?

Comment: You need axiom (2) with "finite" replaced by "countable".  This kind of study is known as measure theory.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Is this related to countable infinity?

Answer (score 1):

Let me recall a very straightforward definition of area.

We define the measure of (oriented) areas of parallelogram in general (in particular a square) by the determinant of the basis vectors "generating" this parallogram. In this way, taking a direct orthonormal basis $(\vec{i},\vec{j})$, and imposing $det(\vec{i},\vec{j})=1$, we have

$$det(\vec{Li},\vec{Lj})=L^2 det(\vec{i},\vec{j})=L^2.$$

Remark: A more general setting uses exterior calculus, with a linear transformation T, knowing that $dim(\Lambda_n)=1$, $det(T)$ is defined as the following coefficient of proportionality:

$$(Te_1) \wedge (Te_2) \wedge \cdots \wedge (Te_n) = det(T) (e_1 \wedge e_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge  e_n)$$

I understand that you consider a different process that tries, in a "Greek" fashion,  to promote the use of integers as long as it is possible, but I wanted to recall here the fundamentals of a now classical view initiated by Legendre in his "Eléments de Géométrie" (1794).

Comment: This is unfortunately far beyond my knowledge of Mathematics

Comment: Sorry for that. I didn't know to which level I could present things. Nevertheless, I find that you ask a good question.